# How to select a floating-point or integer using a regular expression from text

Tags: regex, ruby

I want to match a given integer or floating-point number from some text, but constrained to a particular line, because similar numbers can appear in different locations.

This is what I have as input, the numbers are made up, don't try to correlate "total" with "partials":

```
===> Verifying dependencies...
===> Compiling sample
===> Performing cover analysis...
  |------------------------|------------|
  |                module  |  coverage  |
  |------------------------|------------|
  |            sample_app  |    12.94%  |
  |            sample_sup  |    56.78%  |
  |                sample  |       96%  |
  |------------------------|------------|
  |                 total  |    23.02%  |
  |------------------------|------------|
  coverage calculated from:
    /tmp/workspace/_build/test/cover/ct.coverdata
    /tmp/workspace/_build/test/cover/eunit.coverdata
  cover summary written to: /tmp/workspace/_build/test/cover/index.html
```

I want to extract **only** `23.02`, thus it is, the number from the line with `total`. This is the regular expression that I have so far:

```
^.+total.+(\d+|\d+\.\d+)%.+$
```

but it doesn't work well, it only matches the last digit on that line.

I'm testing the pattern on [Rubular](https://rubular.com/r/DigjNUywoUOWNHl).

Comment: Are you sure about `^` and `$`? You almost always want `\A` and `\z` (respectively) in Ruby.

Comment: I was testing with those at the time I posted this; I ended up with this: `/^.+total\D+(\d+|\d+\.\d+)%.+$/` ...works well for what I want.

Comment: The more complex the pattern, the more likely it'll break or have holes in it, so keep them simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems. The first is that `.+` is greedy, meaning that, if used to search a single line from the file, it will gobble up as many characters as it can (other than newlines) yet still secure a match, which means matching the last digit.

The second problem is that if you read the file into a string and search the string, `.*` will not go past the first line, because it will not match newline characters. That can be easily addressed by adding a multiline modifier (`/m`) which directs `.*` to match all characters, including newlines.

If you read your file into a string you could use the following regular expressions to extract the characters of interest from the string.

```
r = /
    ^          # match beginning of line
    [ ]*       # match 0+ spaces
    \|         # match a toothpick
    [ ]+       # match 1+ spaces
    total      # match 'total'   
    [ ]+       # match 1+ spaces
    \|         # match a toothpick
    [ ]+       # match 1+ spaces
    \K         # forget everything matched so far
    \d+        # match a digit
    (?:\.\d+)  # match '.' then 1+ digits in non-capture group
    ?          # optionally match the non-capture group
    (?=        # begin a positive lookahead
      %        # match '%'
      [ ]+     # match '%' then 1+ spaces
      \|[ ]*   # match a toothpick then 0+ spaces
      $        # match end-of-line
    )          # end positive lookahead
    /x         # free-spacing mode
```

I've written the regex in free-spacing mode<sup>1</sup> to make it self-documenting. It is conventionally written as follows.

```
/^ *\| +total +\| +\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=% +\| *$)/
```

Suppose you read your file into a string held by the variable `str`:

```
str =<<~END
===> Verifying dependencies...
===> Compiling sample
===> Performing cover analysis...
  |------------------------|------------|
  |                module  |  coverage  |
  |------------------------|------------|
  |            sample_app  |    12.94%  |
  |            sample_sup  |    56.78%  |
  |                sample  |       96%  |
  |------------------------|------------|
  |                 total  |    23.02%  |
  |------------------------|------------|
  coverage calculated from:
    /tmp/workspace/_build/test/cover/ct.coverdata
    /tmp/workspace/_build/test/cover/eunit.coverdata
  cover summary written to: /tmp/workspace/_build/test/cover/index.html
END
```

Then

```
str[r] #=> "23.02"
```

<sup>1 In free-spacing mode all spaces are stripped out before the regex is parsed, which is why spaces that are part of the regex must be protected. I've done that by putting each space in character class, but they could instead be escaped or `\s` could be used (if appropriate).</sup>

Comment: @Thefourthbird, I only tested with the regex in free-spacing mode, and when I put that in your link it works fine. I figure I must have made a mistake converting the free-spacing mode version to the normal version. I'll check and fix. Addendum: I left out a toothpick.

Comment: @Thefourthbird, I corrected the non-free-spacing regex. If it is held by `r`, `str[r] #=> "23.02"`, as expected. It also works with [PCRE](https://regex101.com/r/e86zz1/1/) which supports the same features that I've used. It does not work with [Rubular](https://rubular.com/r/hpGQlQ2MqiOLSy) however, even though the free-spacing version does. Any idea why?

Comment: I think you have spaces after the pattern https://rubular.com/r/fXLas7w4OFXWmQ

Comment: Thanks, @Thefourthbird, and thanks for the heads-up in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I like to keep it simple and would use this:

```
text = <<EOT
===> Verifying dependencies...
===> Compiling sample
===> Performing cover analysis...
  |------------------------|------------|
  |                module  |  coverage  |
  |------------------------|------------|
  |            sample_app  |    12.94%  |
  |            sample_sup  |    56.78%  |
  |                sample  |       96%  |
  |------------------------|------------|
  |                 total  |    23.02%  |
  |------------------------|------------|
  coverage calculated from:
    /tmp/workspace/_build/test/cover/ct.coverdata
    /tmp/workspace/_build/test/cover/eunit.coverdata
  cover summary written to: /tmp/workspace/_build/test/cover/index.html
EOT

text[/ total .+ ([\d.]+)/, 1] # => "23.02"
```

https://regex101.com/r/SXtXVx/2 demonstrates and explains the pattern.

"`total`" is so sub-string matches don't occur.

Alternately, this would work:

```
text.lines.find { |l| l[' total '] }[/[\d.]+/] # => "23.02"
```

That works by letting Ruby break the text into an array of individual lines, finding the one containing `total`, then extracting the floating-point number.

```
text.lines # => ["===> Verifying dependencies...\n", "===> Compiling sample\n", "===> Performing cover analysis...\n", "  |------------------------|------------|\n", "  |                module  |  coverage  |\n", "  |------------------------|------------|\n", "  |            sample_app  |    12.94%  |\n", "  |            sample_sup  |    56.78%  |\n", "  |                sample  |       96%  |\n", "  |------------------------|------------|\n", "  |                 total  |    23.02%  |\n", "  |------------------------|------------|\n", "  coverage calculated from:\n", "    /tmp/workspace/_build/test/cover/ct.coverdata\n", "    /tmp/workspace/_build/test/cover/eunit.coverdata\n", "  cover summary written to: /tmp/workspace/_build/test/cover/index.html\n"]
    .find { |l| l['total'] } # => "  |                 total  |    23.02%  |\n"
```

In both cases, `/[\d.]+/]` is all it takes to match a floating point or integer number:

```
' 1.2 '[/[\d.]+/] # => "1.2"
' 12  '[/[\d.]+/] # => "12"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
text = <<~TEXT
===> Verifying dependencies...
===> Compiling sample
===> Performing cover analysis...
  |------------------------|------------|
  |                module  |  coverage  |
  |------------------------|------------|
  |            sample_app  |    12.94%  |
  |            sample_sup  |    56.78%  |
  |                sample  |       96%  |
  |------------------------|------------|
  |                 total  |    23.02%  |
  |------------------------|------------|
  coverage calculated from:
    /tmp/workspace/_build/test/cover/ct.coverdata
    /tmp/workspace/_build/test/cover/eunit.coverdata
  cover summary written to: /tmp/workspace/_build/test/cover/index.html
TEXT

text.lines.find { |line| line.match?(/total/) }[/\d+\.?(\d+)?/].to_f
# => 23.02
```

Firstly you convert your string to array using [`String#lines`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-lines).

Then you find line with total using [`Enumerable#find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-find).

Then using [`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) get match data (integer or float).

And finally convert this match data to `Float`.

Comment: I have to use a regular expression in Ruby, but I cannot use Ruby; this is to extract that number in order to be used in a GitLab CI/CD pipeline. The regular expression is used only in their YAML (declarative) configuration for the pipelines.